# What is the determinant of an English native speaker?

Tags: speech

It could be argued that only native speakers of English from England are true native speakers. Other countries that have adopted English as their primary language (America, Australia, Canada) have cultural and language differences, spelling, pronunciation etc.

Comment: Can you, please, clarify your question?

Comment: What is your definition of "primary language" and "native language"? Do you mean English is the native language of England, but not that of Australia, for example?

Comment: And let's extend Rathony's question. Is the OP suggesting Scots, Irish, Welsh, Manx are non-native speakers? Obviously that's ridiculous.

Comment: Anyway agree it's a duplicate

Comment: You could just as well argue that about most of England itself. Spelling differences are so minuscule as to be insignificant. Cultural differences do not affect whether something is a different language or not. And pronunciation isn't a very reliable guide either—standard RP or Estuary English is much closer to many Australian and South African dialects than it is to a thick Scouse accent, both in terms of vocabulary, grammar, and pronunciation.

Comment: This question appears to be an exact copy of [this answer to a different question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/338409/47827)… which doesn’t exactly make things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

One's country of origin has less to do today with the language one is brought up to speak as one's first language than ever before in history. Thus, if one is brought up to speak English as one's first language, then that person is a native speaker of English -- with all of its wonderful regional variants.

Answer (score 0):

All over the world there are countries where the native language is English.

You can look the list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_entities_where_English_is_an_official_language)

The English language is almost the same, If you understand English from London, You can understand the English of Australian native speaker too (and everyone speaks English).

There are a bit of differences in every type of English, like slang, accent and some words.

Example: In American a lot of people use "What's up", In England almost nobody does it. In American everyone says "color", in British "colour".

I can't explain every differences, You can search on Google `Difference between english and [other english language, like Scottish etc.]` for get a lot of differences between English and other types of English.

I link  you this article ["What Are The Differences Between American And British English?"](http://difference%20between%20english%20and%20american)

But in the web you can found more thing about it!